# Mini-Filter intercept drag & drop file(s) to disk?

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, driver, minifilter, kernel-mode

I am developing a mini-filter to **intercept files and get the name of files** which are dragged & dropped to a specific disk and get the file names.

If I drag & drop a file, I can get this file name and intercept it successfully (That's mean this file is not created on disk).

If I drag & drop multiple files, I can only get the first file name and other is not. But when I open the disk, I don't see any file here (That's mean Mini-Filter intercept them successfully). **So I can not get the file names (except the first file)**

I intercept drag & drop by redirect them:

1. Get file name by FltGetFileNameInformation() then FltParseFileNameInformation()
2. Split it two part

   - First is: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\folder\
   - Second is: file.ext
3. Append a file name for first part: \Device\HarddiskVolume1\folder\new_file.ext
4. Intercept create on disk

   - Release this buffer: Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName.Buffer
   - Assign first part to Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName
   - Set this: Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->RelatedFileObject = NULL;
   - Data->IoStatus.Information = IO_REPARSE;
   - Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_REPARSE;
   - return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;

Above code can only intercept all files and get the first file name.

How can I do to intercept each file when I drag & drop multiple file?

Comment: I redirect file depending on [redirect-file-open-using-windows](http://www.codingnotebook.com/2013/05/redirect-file-open-using-windows.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself that:

1. Get file name from Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName

   - Slipt it two part: file path and file name
   - Change file name to a redirect file name
2. [Delete redirect file name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212998/how-to-delete-a-file-from-kernel-mode). This step can be run before step #1

   - If redirect file name is not exist, It return STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND (0xC0000034). It is not problem for system.
   - If redirect file name is exist. It is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the [simrep](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/simrep) sample from Microsoft they show you how to properly do this.
I would not base my assumption that Drag&Drop has a correspondence in the kernel and in the file-system. It can be implemented in user-mode in many ways especially if you are doing it on the same volume. It can be as simple as a rename. Also keep in mind hard-links and symboliclinks and alternate data streams.

Good luck.