# How to delete a file from kernel-mode?

Tags: c, windows, driver, minifilter, kernel-mode

I have a minifilter (kernel-mode). I want to delete a file with specific path (\Device\HarddiskVolume1\file.txt or C:\file.txt) from kernel-mode

Is there any way to do that?

**UPDATE: 20150130**

I try to use [ZwDeleteFile routine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as [Harry Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212998/how-to-delete-a-file-from-kernel-mode/28225210#28225210) said. These are my codes:

```
RtlInitUnicodeString(&gRedirectFullFilePath, "\\Device\\HarddiskVolume1\\test.txt"); // This file existed
InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjectAttribute, &gRedirectFullFilePath, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL); 
status = ZwDeleteFile(&ObjectAttribute);
```

But it crash my system. Is there anything wrong with my codes? => fixed (This is answer)

Thanks!

Comment: The string is missing a backslash, though I wouldn't expect that to cause a crash.  Why is `pObjectAttribute` a pointer?  Normally it would be a local variable.  Is this a file system minifilter driver?  I'm not sure whether it is legal to call ZwDeleteFile() in that context.  Also check the documented requirements regarding IRQL and special kernel APCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ZwDeleteFile routine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The ZwDeleteFile routine deletes the specified file.

Answer (score 1):

By usual methods its not possible to delete the file from kernel mode i.e from device driver.

This kind of practice or idea is highly discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FltSetInformationFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with `FileDispositionInformation` class.

Comment: I delete file from a specific string not in file object.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in which you can do that as illustrated in the minifilter [DeleteSample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/delete) from Microsoft.

1. [FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/delete-on-close) flag which you can use in you CreateFile routine of choice.
2. By setting the [FileDispositionInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information)
3. Also notice the newly introduced [FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION_EX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information_ex)

Everything should be more clear after you study the sample.
Also notice that you could do transactioned deletes and also delete a file by its file ID.

Good luck.