# Minifilter how to change file size?

Tags: c++, windows, driver, minifilter, windows-kernel

I am develop a minifilter to detect drag & drop file to harddisk. When user drag & drop file to drive:

1. Change file name to a specified file name. Ex: redirect_file_name.txt
2. Then I delete this file.

But the size of file redirect_file_name.txt does not change.

1. If source file's size is 1GB, redirect_file_name.txt is 1GB
2. If source file's size is 100MB, redirect_file_name.txt is 100MB

I change source name to redirect_file_name.txt by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28209772/mini-filter-intercept-drag-drop-files-to-disk)

How can I do to change the size of file redirect_file_name.txt?

**UPDATE: Use FltSetInformationFile with FileAllocationInformation**

```
FILE_ALLOCATION_INFORMATION fileInformation;
fileInformation.AllocationSize.QuadPart = 1024;
status = FltSetInformationFile( FltObjects->Instance,
                          FltObjects->FileObject,
                          &fileInformation,
                          sizeof(FILE_ALLOCATION_INFORMATION),
                          FileAllocationInformation);
```

But status is 0XC000000D (STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER)

Comment: According to the other post that you link, you are trying to delete the redirected file. So, I understand that the delete ZwDeleteFile is not working. In which IRP are you trying to delete the file? What is the return of ZwDeleteFile? Some code would be a good point to see what is happening.

Comment: ZwDeleteFile is success. But if I don't use ZwDeleteFile to delete redirect file, I see the size of file to be same with the source file. So I want to change the size of file when I drag & drop to drive. **I want to change the size of file**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use these code at IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (as said on Remarks)

```
FILE_ALLOCATION_INFORMATION fileInformation;
fileInformation.AllocationSize.QuadPart = 1024; // Size of file
status = FltSetInformationFile( FltObjects->Instance,
                          FltObjects->FileObject,
                          &fileInformation,
                          sizeof(FILE_ALLOCATION_INFORMATION),
                          FileAllocationInformation);
```